# i have a query problems

Tags: sql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ideas_tbl (idea, desc) VALUES ('$idea', '$desc')";
```

Comment: `desc` is a SQL key word (think `ORDER BY`).  I vote to close such questions as simple typographic errors.

Comment: It's vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection_attack). To avoid this, and a lot of other problems, use [bind parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values).

Comment: @GordonLinoff A typo would be if they'd written "INSRT" instead of "INSERT". Not knowing that "desc" is a keyword is legit. Write your comment up as an answer and I'd upvote it. :)

Comment: thanks, desc was the problem

Comment: @Schwern . . . They should know that `desc` is a SQL keyword (it is a common keyword used with `ORDER BY`).  I view that as a typographical error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because we all carefully study and memorize language and tool specifications. :P Yeah. People "should" know a lot of things. They don't and that's why they're here asking questions. We call it "learning". And there's a lot of value to asking experts, just look at all the things I got to teach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[As @GordonLinoff mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) the problem is `desc` is a SQL keyword. Used like that, the SQL server might see it as a piece of syntax, not a column name, and get confused. The list of SQL keywords is different from server to server, but [here's a good baseline list from SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

There's two solutions. First is to quote the column with `"`. Some databases will use `` ` `` (MySQL) or `[]` (Microsoft), but `"` is the SQL standard. The non-conforming databases can be configured to support the `"` standard, for example, [MySQL has ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes).

This also means either escaping the quote, or my preferred option, using [balanced quoting operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) (assuming this is Perl).

```
$query = qq[INSERT INTO ideas_tbl (idea, "desc") VALUES ('$idea', '$desc')];
```

I don't like this option because it means every time that column is used you have to remember to quote it. The better option is to rename the column to something else like "description".

---

Now let's talk about your security hole. Because you've put variables straight into the query string your code is vulnerable to a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is one of the most common security holes. If `$idea` or `$desc` come from user input, a clever person can craft some data that can jump out of the quotes and be interpreted as more SQL. This can also happen innocently, like if `$desc = "Our prices can't be beat!"`

You could do all sorts of quoting, but to fully defeat it, and to speed up your code a bit, use [prepared statements and bind parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values). Here I am assuming this is Perl using DBI.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
    INSERT INTO ideas_tbl
           (idea, description)
    VALUES (?,    ?     )
};
$sth->execute($idea, $desc);
```

The other advantage is now you can reuse this statement handle avoiding the overhead of having to recompile it. Like if you were looping through a list of ideas.

```
for my $idea (@ideas) {
    $sth->execute( $idea->{idea}, $idea->{desc} );
}
```

---

Finally, I suspect you didn't get an error message when your query failed which is why you're asking the question. Unfortunately DBI doesn't treat SQL errors as errors by default. If you forget the `or die` after every query you won't get an error.

To avoid this, turn on [RaiseError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) either when you connect (best) or afterwards.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, { RaiseError => 1 });

or

$dbh->RaiseError(1);
```

Now all failed queries will raise an error. No need to remember to put `or die "Something failed because $DBI::errstr"` on every query.